# Call: vibrate, Whatsapp: don't vibrate

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, vibration

When I'm at work, I'd like to put my Nexus 5 (Marshmallow) on silent. My definition of silent is: for incoming calls the phone should vibrate, for everything else (i.e. messages) I don't want any sounds or vibrations. How can I get this working? Do I need a 3rd party app? Thanks a lot!

Fuad

Comment: There is a built-in function in Marshmallow. Slide down the quick settings panel, you will find a 'do not disturb' icon. Tap on it and choose the option 'priority only'

Comment: Thanks Nicola, but that option doesn't do exactly what I want. I.e., it completely mutes messages but allows the phone to go off when I receive a call. I'd rather have it vibrate instead. Any ideas?

Comment: The 'do not disturb' mode allows only certain notifications to pass. And that is its only purpose. Once a notification/call/alarm is allowed, the phone handles it normally, which means: if you have the notification volume turned up, the phone will ring. Just set vibration, by turning the volume all the way down, and for the allowed calls it will vibrate.